# Testing 4 different variables in a switch statement powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, case

I have 4 variables,
$a = 1
$b = 0
$c = 0
$d = 1

I'd like to have 15 different outputs based on which variables have a 1 assigned.
a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd, and abcd

How do I write this case so that it inputs each one? The only exmaples I've been able to find have 1 parameter passed into the statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concat them as strings:

```
switch ("$a" + "$b" + "$c" +"$d")
{
   "1000" { Write-Output "a!" }
   "0100" { Write-Output "b!" }
   "0110" { Write-Output "bc!" }
}
```